# How to get label prediction of binary image classification from Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-classification

How to get label prediction of binary image classification from Tensorflow ?

Enviroment:

- Google colab
- Tensorflow 2.7.0
- Python 3.7.12

Dataset Structure:

```
/training/<br/>
---/COVID19/<br/>
------/img1.jpg<br/>
------/img2.jpg<br/>
------/img3.jpg<br/>
---/NORMAL/<br/>
------/img4.jpg<br/>
------/img5.jpg<br/>
------/img6.jpg<br/>
```

Make Dataset Code:

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 300    
img_width = 300
epochs = 10
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE


dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/fdataset/Dataset.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('training', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=123,
  subset="training",
  validation_split=0.8,
  image_size=(img_width, img_height),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=123,
  subset="validation",
  validation_split=0.2,
  image_size=(img_width, img_height),
  batch_size=batch_size)

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

The Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet121(input_shape=input_shape,include_top=False)
base_model.trainable=True
model.add(base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

loss function: `binary_crossentropy`
optimizer : `RMSprop`
metrics : `accuracy`

after I make a model and train it, I make a prediction with a validation dataset using this code

```
(model.predict(val_ds) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

so I got the result like this

```
array([[0],
   [1],
   [1],
   [0],
   [0]], dtype=int32)
```

then how to convert it again to label like "COVID19" or "NORMAL" the example like this:

```
array([["COVID19"],
   ["NORMAL"],
   ["NORMAL"],
   ["COVID19"],
   ["COVID19"]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the desired values into the array

```
mapper = {1: "NORMAL", 0: "COVID19"}
np.vectorize(mapper.get)(output)
```

Comment: How to make sure 1 is "NORMAL" and 0 is "COVID19"?

Comment: The dictionary says it. @FianJulio

Comment: Keras takes in the values in alphabetical order from the dataset directories. In your case `COVID19` and then `NORMAL`. So the labels correspond to 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vishnudev, that's the answer I was looking for